# How to Increment Dynamic field ngModel name in Angularjs..?

Tags: angularjs

Here when i click Add Product Button it creates a text field. But I want to create create different name for each text box in `ng-model="column.product_cgst"`.
like `column.product_cgst-1, column.product_cgst-2`.

```
<form>
    <div ng-repeat="column in columns" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="product_name" ng-model="column.product_name" required placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control"
                id="userName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="units" ng-model="column.units" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select Units</option>
                <option ng-repeat="units in allunits" value="{{units.unit_id}}">
                    {{units.unit_name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="cgst" type="text" ng-model="column.product_cgst" placeholder="Enter CGST" required class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <input id="sgst" type="text" ng-model="column.product_sgst" placeholder="Enter SGST" required class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="igst" type="text" ng-model="column.product_igst" placeholder="Enter IGST" required class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button class="remove btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="removeColumn($index)">x</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-right m-b-0">
        <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
        <button class="addfields btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="addProduct()">Add Product</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.columns = [];
$scope.addProduct = function () {
    var newItemNo = $scope.columns.length + 1;
    $scope.columns.push({ 'colId': 'col' + newItemNo });
};

$scope.removeColumn = function (index) {
    $scope.columns.splice(index, 1);
    if ($scope.columns.length() === 0 || $scope.columns.length() == null) {
        alert('no rec');
        $scope.columns.push = [{ "colId": "col1" }];
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: You can just change your html files directly with your product_cgst-1, product_cgst-2, product_cgst-3 models. I don't understand your issue.

Comment: You can hard code your ng-model like column.product_cgst-1,column.product_cgst-2,column.product_cgst-3.

Comment: Brother if i want to add more than 25 products at a time then ,it is not possible to hard code .So when ever i add aproduct (if i add 10 product at a time then i want the different ngModel name because i want to insert 10 products at a time).please help to some usefull resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the Solutions here,only change in my angularjs controllers.

//Add Dynamic Column

$scope.columns = [{id: 'firstField'}];

```
$scope.addProduct = function(){
    var newItemNo = $scope.columns.length+1;
    $scope.columns.push({'id':'field'+newItemNo});

}
```

//Remove Dynamic Column

$scope.removeColumn = function() {

```
    var itemLast = $scope.columns.length-1;
    $scope.columns.splice(itemLast);

};
```

//Insert Data in Database:-

$scope.productAdd = function(){

```
    $http.post('product/insert_product', $scope.columns)
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index in the HTML to increment your ng-model dynamically instead of doing in controller.

Using $index in the interpolation with ngModel will not work. Try something like below

```
column.product_cgst[$index]
```

Comment: I am try in my view with {{$index}} but its not work.

Comment: Can u pls clarify whether you were using Using interpolation directly in ngModel?

Comment: Brother See above image.I want to dynamically generate ng-model value different of cgst if i add 25 products at a time then i want to generate 25 different ng-model value for my cgst field.Because i want to insert 25 different at a time in database.So please help.....

Comment: hope the following link helps: https://coderwall.com/p/r7bl4w/ng-repeat-index-for-a-form-field-array-ie-add-new-option